# How to POST unique values to multiple dictionaries using curl

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, curl, flask

I am writing a REST api with Flask, which should create a Dictionary of Dictionaries, e.g.

```
Dictionary = {
        dict1 = {},
        dict2 = {}
        }
```

I would like each dict to be filled with individual values, and I would like to fill both dicts in one request, if possible.

So far I have been testing my code with curl requests, and it seems like it is almost there... except for that both dicts are being filled with the same collection of values.

**api.py**

```
dictionary = {}

@app.route('/launch', methods=['POST'])
def launch():
    gw_type = request.json['type']

    for t in gw_type:
        dictionary[t] = {
            'client': request.json['client']
            'band': request.json['band']
            'password': request.json['password']

    return jsonify(**dictionary)
```

**Curl request**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X 
POST -d '{"type":["type1", "type2"], "client":["test1", "test2"], 
"bands":["ABCD", "ABC"], "password":["pass", "pass2"]}' 
http://localhost:5000/launch
```

**Output**

```
{
  "type1": {
    "bands": [
      "ABCD",
      "ABC"
  ],
  "client": [
    "test1",
    "test2"
  ],
  "password": [
    "pass",
    "pass2"
  ]
},
"type2": {
  "bands": [
    "ABCD",
    "ABC"
  ],
  "client": [
    "test1",
    "test2"
  ],
  "password": [
    "pass",
    "pass2"
  ]
 }
}
```

If it is possible, how would I go about creating the multiple dictionaries ('type'), so that each TYPE has it's own unique values for 'client', 'band' and 'password' in one curl request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are accessing the entire list of `client` `bands` and `password` everytime. If they are ordered in the curl command the way you want then all you need to do is modify your code to use indexes for the correct values:

```
@app.route('/launch', methods=['POST'])
def launch():
    gw_type = request.json['type']

    for i in range(len(gw_type)):
        dictionary[gw_type[i]] = {
            'client': request.json['client'][i]
            'band': request.json['band'][i]
            'password': request.json['password'][i]

    return jsonify(**dictionary)
```

This will get the first client for the first type, the first band for the first type, the second client for the second type, etc.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much - I had a feeling my for loop wasn't doing what I wanted, and I just couldn't see how to fix it.